# In Ruby, why does end_with?("") always return true for any string?

Tags: ruby

I recently ran into a bit of a Ruby language oddity while writing some code. It turns out any string will return `true` if you check if it `end_with?` an empty string.
Why is that? It seems counter intuitive to to me that:

```
"hello".end_with?("")
=> true
```

Returns true. There is a [test case](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0db58dd0db092af8055372d97961bc3399a25767/spec/ruby/shared/string/end_with.rb#L16) explicitly checking for this on the `end_with?` method.

In my opinion only `""` should `end_with?` `""`. But there might be something I don't know. I am just curious as to why this is the expected behavior?

Comment: You would probably agree that `(str + suffix).end_with?(suffix)` should return `true`. Now set `str = "hello"` and `suffix = ""`.

Comment: The better question is why you would ever want to do this, and why this would ever matter to you?

Comment: @Chris this came up while I was working on a PR for a third party gem I am using where a YML file is used to enter domains to block from singing up. My PR augmented the gem to allow for partial domain matching, however, The YML File had an empty line, which translates to nil on the code, and so I did a `nil.to_s` and ran into the curious behavior...

Comment: @Stefan I do of course agree with that, as I am sure you would agree `"hello"` ends with an `"o"`.

Comment: Did some more digging on this and it turns out this is by definition, an empty string is always part of any other string, and it is at the start of and at the end of any other string as well as in between every character of any string. Essentially an empty string is everywhere in any other string... Interesting.

Here is my reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/test-for-empty-strings-and-missing-values.html

Comment: @rii *"The YML File had an empty line, which translates to nil on the code, and so I did a nil.to_s and ran into the curious behavior"* -- The fix here is not to call `.to_s`, and instead correct the YAML file. Maybe even validate the YAML file beforehand?

Comment: @rii there's no contradiction. `"hello"` does end with `"o"`. But `"o"` is the same as `"o" + ""`. Therefore, `"hello"` ends with `"o" + ""` and also just with `""`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mathematical logic, there is the concept of a [*Vacuous Truth*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). For example, if you make a universally quantified statement about all elements of an empty set, this statement is said to be *vacuously true* – after all, since the set is empty, you will not be able to provide a counter example!

If I say "All my children are girls", that statement is *vacuously true*, since I don't have any children. In order to disprove the statement that all my children are girls, you would have to prove that at least one of my children is not a girl … but you can't prove that, because I don't have any children. Therefore, my statement "All my children are girls" is true.

That is why, for example, [`Enumerable#all?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) always returns `true` for an empty `Enumerable`.

While the concept you are asking about is not the same, there is also a logical idea behind it. In [formal language theory](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language), it is often assumed that there are empty strings (usually denoted ***ε***) at the beginning and end of every string and in between any two adjacent symbols.

[Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76715080/2988) shows an example where *not* having a string end with an empty string leads to a logical inconsistency where you append something to the end of a string but then the string doesn't end with what you just appended.

Comment: Very interesting, this is what I eventually ended up discovering as well and you have explained it masterfully. I have accepted your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in comments, if it didn't work this way, the following would not work. `foo` should always return `true`, but if all strings didn't end in `""`, it wouldn't.

```
irb(main):001:1* def foo(a, b)
irb(main):002:1*   (a + b).end_with? b
irb(main):003:0> end
=> :foo
irb(main):004:0> foo("hello", "world")
=> true
irb(main):005:0> foo("hello", "")
=> true
```

It seems unlikely you will ever test that a string ends in `""` in any kind of practical program.

Comment: Unlikely does not mean impossible, I ran into this by pure chance. I answered on the comments under the question. But to be specific here is where I ran into the issue: https://github.com/hallelujah/valid_email/blob/51f61204b482c8765ed158c250a8e6d2eafbb584/lib/valid_email/validate_email.rb#L134